# It is fine if we store the Chat GPT api key inside the SPFx web part properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, spfx-webparts, security

I want to embed a chat GPT inside our SharePoint and i found this web part @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-chat-gpt .but the issue is that it stores the Chat GPT API key inside the web part properties which will be available to all users ,,,so is this fine from a security perceptive ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, secret API keys shouldn't be shared client side. If you're exposing the API key client side, then a user could share it with other people outside of your organisation. OpenAI have provided some best practices for API key safety:

[Best Practices for API Key Safety](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety)

Comment: yes i agree the approach is very unsecure.. so could this SPFx provides a more secure way @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-chatgpt-app where the api key will be stored inside azure function app settings?

Comment: Looking at that SPFx project, it doesn't store the API key in the SPFx web part settings. A prerequisite of the project is to create an Azure Function app where the API key is stored as an app setting.

Comment: so it should be fine to use  it then, as the azure function configuration settings are secured, am i correct?

Comment: Correct, it's not using web part settings to store the API key. Azure web app settings are only accessible to those with access to the web app settings and the app itself. I personally, would store the API key in an Azure Key Vault and access the API from the Key Vault using managed identity.